# Coloring heightmap faces instead of vertices

Tags: java, algorithm, opengl, shader, lwjgl

I'm trying to create a heightmap colored by face, instead of vertex. For example, this is what I currently have:

[image: My terrain, by vertex]
But this is what I want:
[image: Per face coloring]

I read that I have to split each vertex into multiple vertices, then index each separately for the triangles. I also know that blender has a function like this for its models (split vertices, or something?), but I'm not sure what kind of algorithm I would follow for this. This would be the last resort, because multiplying the amount of vertices in the mesh for no reason other than color doesn't seem efficient.

I also discovered something called flatshading (using the `flat` qualifier on the pixel color in the shaders), but it seems to only draw squares instead of triangles. Is there a way to make it shade triangles?

[image: Flatshaded]

For reference, this is my current heightmap generation code:

```
public class HeightMap extends GameModel {

private static final float START_X = -0.5f;
private static final float START_Z = -0.5f;
private static final float REFLECTANCE = .1f;

public HeightMap(float minY, float maxY, float persistence, int width, int height, float spikeness) {
    super(createMesh(minY, maxY, persistence, width, height, spikeness), REFLECTANCE);
}

protected static Mesh createMesh(final float minY, final float maxY, final float persistence, final int width,
        final int height, float spikeness) {
    SimplexNoise noise = new SimplexNoise(128, persistence, 2);// Utils.getRandom().nextInt());

    float xStep = Math.abs(START_X * 2) / (width - 1);
    float zStep = Math.abs(START_Z * 2) / (height - 1);

    List<Float> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int z = 0; z < height; z++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            // scale from [-1, 1] to [minY, maxY]
            float heightY = (float) ((noise.getNoise(x * xStep * spikeness, z * zStep * spikeness) + 1f) / 2
                    * (maxY - minY) + minY);

            positions.add(START_X + x * xStep);
            positions.add(heightY);
            positions.add(START_Z + z * zStep);

            // Create indices
            if (x < width - 1 && z < height - 1) {
                int leftTop = z * width + x;
                int leftBottom = (z + 1) * width + x;
                int rightBottom = (z + 1) * width + x + 1;
                int rightTop = z * width + x + 1;

                indices.add(leftTop);
                indices.add(leftBottom);
                indices.add(rightTop);

                indices.add(rightTop);
                indices.add(leftBottom);
                indices.add(rightBottom);
            }
        }
    }

    float[] verticesArr = Utils.listToArray(positions);
    Color c = new Color(147, 105, 59);
    float[] colorArr = new float[positions.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < colorArr.length; i += 3) {
        float brightness = (Utils.getRandom().nextFloat() - 0.5f) * 0.5f;
        colorArr[i] = (float) c.getRed() / 255f + brightness;
        colorArr[i + 1] = (float) c.getGreen() / 255f + brightness;
        colorArr[i + 2] = (float) c.getBlue() / 255f + brightness;
    }
    int[] indicesArr = indices.stream().mapToInt((i) -> i).toArray();

    float[] normalArr = calcNormals(verticesArr, width, height);

    return new Mesh(verticesArr, colorArr, normalArr, indicesArr);
}

private static float[] calcNormals(float[] posArr, int width, int height) {
    Vector3f v0 = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f v1 = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f v2 = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f v3 = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f v4 = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f v12 = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f v23 = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f v34 = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f v41 = new Vector3f();
    List<Float> normals = new ArrayList<>();
    Vector3f normal = new Vector3f();
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            if (row > 0 && row < height - 1 && col > 0 && col < width - 1) {
                int i0 = row * width * 3 + col * 3;
                v0.x = posArr[i0];
                v0.y = posArr[i0 + 1];
                v0.z = posArr[i0 + 2];

                int i1 = row * width * 3 + (col - 1) * 3;
                v1.x = posArr[i1];
                v1.y = posArr[i1 + 1];
                v1.z = posArr[i1 + 2];
                v1 = v1.sub(v0);

                int i2 = (row + 1) * width * 3 + col * 3;
                v2.x = posArr[i2];
                v2.y = posArr[i2 + 1];
                v2.z = posArr[i2 + 2];
                v2 = v2.sub(v0);

                int i3 = (row) * width * 3 + (col + 1) * 3;
                v3.x = posArr[i3];
                v3.y = posArr[i3 + 1];
                v3.z = posArr[i3 + 2];
                v3 = v3.sub(v0);

                int i4 = (row - 1) * width * 3 + col * 3;
                v4.x = posArr[i4];
                v4.y = posArr[i4 + 1];
                v4.z = posArr[i4 + 2];
                v4 = v4.sub(v0);

                v1.cross(v2, v12);
                v12.normalize();

                v2.cross(v3, v23);
                v23.normalize();

                v3.cross(v4, v34);
                v34.normalize();

                v4.cross(v1, v41);
                v41.normalize();

                normal = v12.add(v23).add(v34).add(v41);
                normal.normalize();
            } else {
                normal.x = 0;
                normal.y = 1;
                normal.z = 0;
            }
            normal.normalize();
            normals.add(normal.x);
            normals.add(normal.y);
            normals.add(normal.z);
        }
    }
    return Utils.listToArray(normals);
}

}
```

**Edit**

I've tried doing a couple things. I tried rearranging the indices with flat shading, but that didn't give me the look I wanted. I tried using a `uniform vec3 colors` and indexing it with gl_VertexID or gl_InstanceID (I'm not entirely sure the difference), but I couldn't get the arrays to compile.
[Here](https://github.com/kyranstar/LWJGL-Game) is the github repo, by the way.

Answer (score 6):

`flat` qualified fragment shader inputs will receive the same value for the same primitive. In your case, a triangle.

Of course, a triangle is composed of 3 vertices. And if the vertex shaders output 3 *different* values, how does the fragment shader know which value to get?

This comes down to what is called the "[provoking vertex](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Provoking_Vertex)." When you render, you specify a particular primitive to use in your `glDraw*` call (`GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, `GL_TRIANGLES`, etc). These primitive types will generate a number of base primitives (ie: single triangle), based on how many vertices you provided.

When a base primitive is generated, one of the vertices in that base primitive is said to be the "provoking vertex". It is that vertex's data that is used for all `flat` parameters.

The reason you're seeing what you are seeing is because the two adjacent triangles just happen to be using the same provoking vertex. Your mesh is smooth, so two adjacent triangles share 2 vertices. Your mesh generation just so happens to be generating a mesh such that the provoking vertex for each triangle is shared between them. Which means that the two triangles will get the same `flat` value.

You will need to adjust your index list or otherwise alter your mesh generation so that this doesn't happen. Or you can just divide your mesh into individual triangles; that's probably much easier.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could divide the mesh into individual triangles?

Comment: @Kyranstar use geometry shader and for each 4 vertexes (`QUAD`) or each new 2 vertexes (`QUAD_STRIP`) emit  2x 3 Vertexes (2x `TRIANGLE`) or rewrite your mesh rendering routine to use `TRIANGLE` primitives directly. Also you should compute the normal for emited primitive to overide the smoothing and duplicate normals due to what this answer describes...

Comment: @Spektre Geometry Shaders in OpenGL are said to be very slow and using one to make triangles out of quads is incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

As a final resort, I just duplicated the vertices, and it seems to work. I haven't been able to profile it to see if it makes a big performance drop. I'd be open to any other suggestions!

```
    for (int z = 0; z < height; z++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            // scale from [-1, 1] to [minY, maxY]
            float heightY = (float) ((noise.getNoise(x * xStep * spikeness, z * zStep * spikeness) + 1f) / 2
                    * (maxY - minY) + minY);

            positions.add(START_X + x * xStep);
            positions.add(heightY);
            positions.add(START_Z + z * zStep);
            positions.add(START_X + x * xStep);
            positions.add(heightY);
            positions.add(START_Z + z * zStep);
        }
    }
    for (int z = 0; z < height - 1; z++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width - 1; x++) {
            int leftTop = z * width + x;
            int leftBottom = (z + 1) * width + x;
            int rightBottom = (z + 1) * width + x + 1;
            int rightTop = z * width + x + 1;

            indices.add(2 * leftTop);
            indices.add(2 * leftBottom);
            indices.add(2 * rightTop);

            indices.add(2 * rightTop + 1);
            indices.add(2 * leftBottom + 1);
            indices.add(2 * rightBottom + 1);
        }
    }
```